# Compiling module from another project

Tags: android, gradle, module, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have my main project with some modules: `:app`, `:anotherModule`, ... .

Then I forked a library on github and pushed it down in another project. It has two modules, a library `:library` and a sample app `:sample`.

What I'm trying to do is to integrate `:library` in my project at compile time, i.e. without copying files (as someone has suggested here).

### What I did

I edited my project settings.gradle and added:

```
include ':library'
project(':library').projectDir = new File(settingsDir,'../ForkedLibrary/library')
```

referencing the folder of the forked library. At the same time I added     `compile project(':library')` to my app module.

### What's wrong

Compiling fails with:

> Could not find property 'ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION' on project ':library'

I know why it happens: `ForkedLibrary/library/build.gradle` is referencing some project values in `ForkedLibrary/gradle.properties`, which is something like:

```
ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION=14
ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=23
ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=23
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=23.0.0
... + LOTS of other stuff, POM_ info, version names, ...
```

I could fix this by copy-pasting these lines into *my project* `gradle.properties`, but it makes no sense to have `:library`-specific stuff in my own gradle properties files. That ForkedLibrary properties files includes things unrelated to my project, like original developer info and other `POM_` fields.

### So

How to solve this (without including `ForkedLibrary` properties in my own `gradle.properties` file)?

Answer (score 0):

It should be a comment, but it is too long. I will delete it if it doesn't help you.

The `ForkedLibrary/library/build.gradle` as you described in your question is using the `ForkedLibrary/gradle.properties`.
It works only in the ForkedLibrary specific project because the other project uses its own `gradle.properties`.

I guess the `library/build.gradle` file has somenthing like:

```
project.VERSION_NAME
```

You can refer the [official doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html):

> The configuration is applied in following order (if an option is configured in multiple locations the last one wins):
>
> - from gradle.properties in project build dir.
> - from gradle.properties in gradle user home.
> - from system properties, e.g. when -Dsome.property is set on the command line.

In this case **you have to copy the properties** in your `build.properties`

There is an **alternative** that I have never tried in this case, something like this:

```
processResources {
    expand(project.properties)
}
```

As you can read in the [official doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/language/jvm/tasks/ProcessResources.html):

> Copies resources from their source to their target directory, potentially processing them. Makes sure no stale resources remain in the target directory.

And the [expand method](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/AbstractCopyTask.html#expand(java.util.Map)) is:

> Expands property references in each file as it is copied.

Comment: Thank you. Copying properties in my own project works, but I'd like to avoid that. Sorry to say, but where exactly should I use processResources?

Comment: It is a task that you can define in your build.gradle files

Comment: I believe you are overestimating my gradle skills :-) the best I could do is copy-paste your lines. Depending on where I do paste it, I get either 'processResources cannot be applied to groovy.lang.Closure' or 'Gradle DSL method not found'.

Comment: I have to check if which version of gradle is required.